# Define range based on the value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to define a range in VBA based on a value given in a cell?

For example, I have a dataset with four columns and a constantly changing number of rows. I have the number of rows in cell `F2`. Suppose cell `F2` indicates the number of rows is `385`, then I be able to  `Range("A1:D385").Select`, but I want the selection of the last cell to be dependent on cell `F2`.

So if I change `F2` to `50`, that the next time I run the macro, `A1:D50` will be selected, but since I'm new to VBA I can't figure it out.

Comment: try `Range("A1:D" & Range("F2").Value2).Select`. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @user3290799 Why not use `Value2`? It's quicker.

Comment: You're right @Rory. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

The most proper way to do this would be like this

```
Sub getRng()
Dim Cval As Variant
Dim Rng1 As Range
Cval = ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Value
Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D" & Cval)
End Sub
```

this sets `Rng1` as an object that you can use later on in another function

such as

`Rng1.Select`

or

`Rng1.Copy`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
    .range("A1:D" & lastRow).Select
End With
```

The code looks for the first non-empty cell in column F, from bottom to top. Similar to selecting the last cell in column F and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up-arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but better to always also explain your answer, rather than just dump code.