# VBA: Setting range (chart) based on two cell values

Tags: excel, vba, graph

Based on "[Define range based on the value of another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717332/define-range-based-on-the-value-of-another-cell)" I`m trying to create a flexible macro that updates the range of a graph. This graph needs to update both coordinates but with a fixed column (letter).

Only problem is, that I`m only able to define the end. Not the start, how should I create this flexible (user input) row input field? The first one is what I proposed, but that doesnt work, the others work, but they only define the end not the start.

```
Sub Example()
'
'

    Dim Cval As Variant
    Dim Dval As Variant
    Cval = Sheets("Settings").Range("C30").Value
    Dval = Sheets("Settings").Range("C31").Value

    Sheets("Chart-16Q1-18Q4").Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$C$" & Cval ":$C$" & Dval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$D$5:$D$" & Dval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$F$5:$F$" & Dval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$G$5:$G$" & Dval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$H$5:$H$" & Dval
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$M$5:$M$" & Dval

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested method should work. You only forgot some `&` and got a compile error:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Calculation_sheet!$C$" & Cval & ":$C$" & Dval
'                                                                       ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid I forgot that one. Your help is greatly appreciated!